# PowerShell logic to search for new string occurrences in one log file

Tags: powershell

Good morning,
I am searching a remote "live" log file for the occurrence of a string,  lets say the string is "Invalid Data".  If this string is found, it means a severe system issue has/is taking place. Its checking every hour (but I will be changing this to more frequently) If the string is found, I am sending an email alert. That is fine. I'm using PowerShell to find the string no problem.

The issue is, that this log file is not time-sliced (and cannot be), so its one big file that grows throughout the day (it becomes date appended at the end of the day), so lets say I find the string at 08:00 - great, email is sent. The problem is, that once the issue is fixed, those string occurrences within the log file are still there and will remain there until the end of the day, so my logic for checking if the string is in the log file is flawed after/if it finds the 1st occurrence of the day,  as it will keep finding the string.

I cant think of how to rectify this flaw. I was thinking of count of occurrences, but this check is checking hundreds of remote devices, so I'm struggling to see how I can utilize that.

The log file looks like (as an example):

```
17-05-2018 09:22:52:391 (07144) .................. bla  bla bla

17-05-2018 09:22:52:391 (07144) .................. bla bla bla

17-05-2018 09:22:52:392 (07144) .................. 

17-05-2018 09:22:52:393 (07144) .................. bla bla

17-05-2018 09:22:52:393 (07144) .................. LoadFileInfo,  

17-05-2018 09:22:52:393 (07144) .................. Invalid Data <--- this being the error
```

So looking for any tips on how I can make my alert more relevant. The fact the date and time is on the left hand side of the log leans me to believe this might be able to be manipulated into some variable maybe and if string found greater  than this variable, trigger? But I'm new to PowerShell, so any pointers greatly appreciated..

Thanks for your time and appreciate any feedback.

Cheers

Comment: The easiest way would be to save the current invalidData count in a file and then you can compare the count each time you execute the script and decide whether you want to alert....

Comment: Simply Replace "Invalid Data" with "Error Founded" if this info is important for you !

Comment: Or have your PowerShell script create a second log file, one for alerts triggered.  As "Invalid Data$" is matched in the live log, if the line doesn't already exist in your alerts triggered log, append the matched line to alerts triggered then send an email.  Something like `$line = $reader.ReadLine(); if ($line -match "Invalid Data$") { gc alerts.log | %{ if ($_ -eq $line) { $reader.Close(); exit 0 } } } else { ac alerts.log $line; $reader.Close() }`

Comment: As @rojo suggested, I would use a separate local file for tracking which lines were already processed. I have a script I run against a SharePoint form library that functions similarly. I scan a form library and performs actions but I don't want to process the same form more than once so I keep track of the forms I have already processed in another file.

Comment: Thanks for the comments all, appreciate your time. Looking over these suggestions. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Can you just run a while loop and check the last line of the log file, it will get stuck in this loop until a match is made, at which point it will continue.

Depending how quickly lines are written to the log, you will want to play with the Start-Sleep

```
while ((Get-Content -Path $LogFilePath -Tail 1 | Select-String -Pattern "Invalid Data" -SimpleMatch) -eq $null) 
{ 
    #Stuck in this loop until a match is made
    Start-Sleep 1 
}
#Send email and then loop back to the beginning
```

Comment: Thanks for the response on this one. Interesting suggestion and not one I had considered.  I'm looking at this with the above suggestions as well and seeing what might best fit